# Different spaces between UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Is it possible to have 2 (or 3) different types of space between UICollectionViewCell?

For example, I want :

- the space between the cell number 2 and  the cell number 3 is 50.f
- the space between the cell number 10 and the cell number 11 is 70.f
- the rest is 100.f

Comment: The easiest to do this is with collection view sections.

Comment: @the4kman I agree, but actually I want to do it between cells, (not sections). Thanks

Comment: Stupid but simple... you can add to cells additional space (UIView where backgroundColor will be clearColor). Then you can determine space between two cells by constraint.constant of this UIView. I do it all the time.